# Jenkins won't run my build script from perforce

Tags: jenkins

I have a build script I created which is located in a perforce streams depot at //HVS/Main/BuildScripts/hvs_client.jenkinsfile. However, when I run it it's just automatically successful. You can see in the image what it's doing.

[image]

I have set the Script Path to the correct location:

[image]

And I also have it setup with the correct stream path:
[image]

This exact setup works just fine on my windows server running jenkins. The only difference is that I'm trying to migrate my jenkins setup off of a physical machine and onto the cloud. The new master which is running on Ubuntu 20.04 is what is having these issues. I also have one "Node" which is a windows server which has the java agent installed and connected.

This is what my pipeline script looks like:

```
def channelId = 'removed_for_stackoverflow'
def threadId
def slackResponse

pipeline {
  agent {label 'Windows'}
  
  parameters {
    choice(name: "BuildType", choices: ['Development', 'Shipping', 'Testing'], description: "What environment are you building to? Default is Development.")
    string(name: "SevenZIPDir", defaultValue: "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe", description: "Location of 7zip executable.")
    booleanParam(name: "clean", description: "Should jenkins clean the workspace?", defaultValue: false)
  }

  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout()
  }

  stages {

    stage('P4 Sync') {
      steps {
          script {
            if (params.clean)
            {
              cleanWs()
            }
            
            p4sync charset: 'none', credential: '5feaca76-6a4a-4540-8a1e-e86ac8b3dc5b', populate: syncOnly(force: false, have: true, modtime: false, parallel: [enable: false, minbytes: '1024', minfiles: '1', threads: '4'], pin: '', quiet: true, revert: false), source: streamSource('//HVS/Main')
          }
      }
    }

    // https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin#bot-user-mode
    // https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/UnrealArchitecture/VersioningAssetsAndPackages/
    // https://www.perforce.com/manuals/jenkins/Content/P4Jenkins/variable-expansion.html
    stage('Notify Slack users') {
      steps {
          script {
            slackResponse = slackSend(channel: channelId, replyBroadcast: true, message: "Beginning build of ${env.JOB_NAME} for CL#${P4_CHANGELIST} ${env.BUILD_URL}")
            threadId = slackResponse.threadId
            slackResponse.addReaction("stopwatch")
          }
      }
    } 
    stage('Build Client') {
      steps {
        retry(3) {
          bat("%WORKSPACE%/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/RunUAT.bat BuildCookRun -project=\"%WORKSPACE%/HVS/HVS.uproject\" -noP4 -platform=Win64 -clientconfig=Development -cook -allmaps -clean -build -stage -pak -CrashReporter -archive -archivedirectory=\"%WORKSPACE%/temp/Development/x64\"")        
        }
      }
    }
    /*stage('Deploy to Steam') {
      
    }*/
    stage('Archive Artifacts'){
            steps {
                dir("temp/${params.BuildType}/x64/WindowsNoEditor") {
                      bat "\"${params.SevenZIPDir}\" a -mx=1 -mmt=on %WORKSPACE%/temp/HVS_${params.BuildType}_x64_${P4_CHANGELIST}.7z *"
                }
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: "temp/*.7z", followSymlinks: false, onlyIfSuccessful: true
            }
        }
  }
  post {
      success {
        script {
          slackSend(channel: threadId, replyBroadcast: true, message: "Build of ${env.JOB_NAME} for CL#${P4_CHANGELIST} successful! ${env.BUILD_URL}")
          slackResponse.addReaction("white_check_mark")
        }
      }
      failure {
        script {
          slackSend(channel: threadId, replyBroadcast: true, message: "Build of ${env.JOB_NAME} for CL#${P4_CHANGELIST} failed! ${env.BUILD_URL}")
          slackResponse.addReaction("red_circle")
        }
      }
      unstable {
        script {
          slackSend(channel: threadId, replyBroadcast: true, message: "Build of ${env.JOB_NAME} for CL#${P4_CHANGELIST} is not stable @channel ${env.BUILD_URL}")
          slackResponse.addReaction("warning")
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Has anyone seen this before? My one "Node" also has the label "Windows"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the Pipeline plugin installd for some reason. It works now.